# Show that $ \ d(d \omega)=0 \ $

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, differential-forms, exterior-algebra

If $ \ \omega=f(x,y,z)dx+g(x,y,z)dy+h(x,y,z)dz \ $ and $ f, \ g , \ h \ $ are smooth functions on $ \mathbb{R}^3 \ $ , then show that $ \ d(d \omega)=0 \ $.

**Answer:**

$$ d \omega=df \wedge dx+dg \wedge dy+dh \wedge dz$$ or  $$d \omega=(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}dz) \wedge dx + (\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}dy+\frac{\partial g}{\partial z}dz) \wedge dy + (\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}dy+\frac{\partial h}{\partial z}dz) \wedge dz $$  or 
$$d (\omega)=(\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial g}{\partial z}) dy \wedge dz+ (\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}-\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}) dz \wedge dx + (\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}) dx \wedge dy $$

**Next I can not proceed to show $ d(d\omega)=0 \ $ anyhow ?**

**Help me out**

Comment: hint: next use the distributive law.

Comment: Expand the parenthesis, and then use $dx \wedge dx = 0$, $dx \wedge dy = - dy \wedge dx$, and similar properties of the exterior algebra.

Comment: expanded  but how to make $ d(d(\omega))=0 $

Comment: @yourmath Now, apply $d$ and expand again!

Comment: I'll edit your question and fix the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your $d\omega$ should be
$$d \omega=(\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial g}{\partial z}) dy \wedge dz+ (\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}-\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}) dz \wedge dx + (\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}-{\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}}) dx \wedge dy ,
$$
so

\begin{align}
d^2 \omega & = d \Big((g_x-f_y) dx \wedge dy + (h_y-g_z)dy\wedge dz + (h_x-f_z)dx \wedge dz \Big) \\  & = (g_{xz} - f_{yz}) dz\wedge dx \wedge dy + (h_{yx}-g_{zx}) dx\wedge dy \wedge dz + (h_{xy}-f_{zy}) dy\wedge dx \wedge dz.
\end{align}

Next, arrange the terms in the second equality into just one term $ (\cdots)\, dx \wedge dy \wedge dz$ and use the fact that $f_{xy}=f_{yx}$ and so on. You'll find that the terms will cancel each other.